# Problema de Required, FormControl y Name="" en Angular

Tags: html5, angular, required

He detectado un problema con la declaración "required" de HTML5 en un formulario reactivo de angular, mi codigo inicial luce asi:

```
<div class="quiz">
  <div class="text-header">
    <h3>¿Ha presenciado o sufrido alguna vez, <b>durante o con motivo del trabajo</b> un acontecimiento como
      los siguientes:</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="quiz-content">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">

        <form [formGroup]="quizForm" (ngSubmit)="sendInfo()" ngNativeValidate autocomplete="off">
          <div class="row form-inner">

            <div class="col-md-12">
              <legend class="radios">Accidente que tenga como consecuencia la muerte, la pérdida de un miembro o una
                lesión grave?</legend>
              <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3; margin: 48px, 0, 48px, 0;">

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input id="afirmativo" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="1" formControlName="respuesta1"
                  required>
                <label class="custom-control-label" style="padding-left: 16px;" for="afirmativo">Si</label>

                <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                  <input id="negativo" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="0" formControlName="respuesta1"
                    required>
                  <label class="custom-control-label" style="padding-left: 16px;" for="negativo">No</label>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="respuesta1.invalid && isValidFormSubmitted != null && !isValidFormSubmitted">
                  Todos los campos son requeridos.
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-12">
              <legend class="radios">Asaltos?</legend>
              <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3; margin: 48px, 0, 48px, 0;">
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input id="afirmativo1" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="1" formControlName="respuesta2"
                  required>
                <label class="custom-control-label" style="padding-left: 16px;" for="afirmativo1">Si</label>
              </div>

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input id="negativo1" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="0" formControlName="respuesta2"
                  required>
                <label class="custom-control-label" style="padding-left: 16px;" for="negativo1">No</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <legend class="radios">Actos violentos que derivaron en lesiones graves?</legend>
              <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3; margin: 48px, 0, 48px, 0;">
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input id="afirmativo2" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="1" formControlName="respuesta3"
                  required>
                <label class="custom-control-label" style="padding-left: 16px;" for="afirmativo2">Si</label>
              </div>

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input id="negativo2" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="0" formControlName="respuesta3"
                  required>
                <label class="custom-control-label" style="padding-left: 16px;" for="negativo2">No</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <legend class="radios">Secuestro?</legend>
              <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3; margin: 48px, 0, 48px, 0;">
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input id="afirmativo3" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="1" formControlName="respuesta4"
                  required>
                <label class="custom-control-label" style="padding-left: 16px;" for="afirmativo3">Si</label>
              </div>

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input id="negativo3" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="0" formControlName="respuesta4"
                  required>
                <label class="custom-control-label" style="padding-left: 16px;" for="negativo3">No</label>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-12">
              <legend class="radios">Amenazas?</legend>
              <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3; margin: 48px, 0, 48px, 0;">
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input id="afirmativo4" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="1" formControlName="respuesta5"
                  required>
                <label class="custom-control-label" style="padding-left: 16px;" for="afirmativo4">Si</label>
              </div>

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input id="negativo4" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="0" formControlName="respuesta5"
                  required>
                <label class="custom-control-label" style="padding-left: 16px;" for="negativo4">No</label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
              <legend class="radios">Cualquier otro que ponga en riesgo su vida o salud, y/o la de otras personas?
              </legend>
              <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3; margin: 48px, 0, 48px, 0;">
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input id="afirmativo5" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="1" formControlName="respuesta6"
                  required>
                <label class="custom-control-label" style="padding-left: 16px;" for="afirmativo5">Si</label>
              </div>

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input id="negativo5" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="0" formControlName="respuesta6"
                  required>
                <label class="custom-control-label" style="padding-left: 16px;" for="negativo5">No</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-simple submit" type="submit">Continuar</button>

        </form>





      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

el cual ya lo tengo y me funcionaba bien, pero tenia un problema de duplicado de componentes, todos los encimaba como un pergamino, entonces quite la etiqueta

```
name="pregunta1"
```

Y dejo de hacer ese efecto extraño.
Pero ahora no me funciona el **required** a pesar de tener el ngNativeValidate.

Que es lo que causa esto? Acaso el required y el name="" dependen tanto el del otro para funcionar? o sera que debo validar todo con Angular, me gustaria que el **required** vuelva a funcionar, ya que son puros radio button y me ayudaba mucho para filtrar el formulario.

Agradezco sus comentarios.

Agrego el codigo del quiz1.component.ts

```
       import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
        import { Router } from '@angular/router';
        @Component({
            selector: 'app-quiz1',
            templateUrl: 'quiz1.component.html'
        })

        export class Quiz1Component implements OnInit {
export class Quiz1Component implements OnInit {

  isValidFormSubmitted = null;

    quizForm = new FormGroup({
        respuesta1: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        respuesta2: new FormControl(''/* ,Validators.required */),
        respuesta3: new FormControl(''/* ,Validators.required */),
        respuesta4: new FormControl(''/* ,Validators.required */),
        respuesta5: new FormControl(''/* ,Validators.required */),
        respuesta6: new FormControl(''/* ,Validators.required */)

      });
        onInit(){}
        sendInfo(){}
        }
```

EL codigo de mi quiz1.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { Quiz1Component } from './quiz1.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        Quiz1Component,
    ],
    exports: [
        Quiz1Component,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule, 
        ReactiveFormsModule 
       ],
    providers: []
})
export class Quiz1Module {
}
```

El del quiz1.routes.ts

```
import {Route} from '@angular/router';
import { Quiz1Component } from './quiz1.component';

export const Quiz1Routes: Route[] = [
    {
        path: 'quiz1',
        component: Quiz1Component,
        children: []
    }
]
```

;

Comment: Puedes añadir el código del componente para ver como creas el formulario?

Comment: Agregue el codigo de los archivos del componente, es un componenete hijo.

Comment: pero donde creas el `quizForm` eso no sale en los archivos?

Comment: Cierto, me faltaba el fragmento, ya lo agregue

Answer (score 0):

El formulario debe ser así, fijate como se usa `#` y `ngForm`

```
<form #quizForm='ngForm' (ngSubmit)="sendInfo()" autocomplete="off">
```

Y el boton así, fijate como uso el nombre del formulario `quizForm`:

```
<input type="submit" [disabled] = '!quizForm.form.valid' >
```

De esta forma el botón se habilita solo si los campos con `required` están informados.

Comment: Esa sintaxis es para los template driven forms, lo que uso son los reactive forms, si agrego esas opciones me manda error en todo :/ . Habra otra opcion... ?